# How to avoid duplicated meta tags?

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, meta-tags

I'm developing my website with next.js.

**My Question**

The code below is in `_document.js` Head component. These are root meta tags.

```
<meta name="description" content="~~~"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="~~~"/>
```

When pages are dynamically created, these tags are created and inserted in `Item.js`.

```
<meta name="description" content={item.product_description}/>
<meta name="description" content={item.brand_name}/>
```

To avoid duplication of meta tags, I inserted some key="" values in meta refer to Next.js docs, but it didn't work. So, I forced to change contents by using `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const description = document.getElementsByName('description');
    const keywords = document.getElementsByName('keywords');
    description[0].content = item.product_description;
    keywords[0].content = item.brand_name;
    return () => {
        description[0].content = '~~~';
        keywords[0].content = '~~~';
    }
}, [])
```

But this way seems wrong. How can I avoid duplicated meta tags more clearly?

I want to get my meta tags for latest one.

[image]

Comment: Try setting the meta tags in your custom `_app` rather than `_document`.

Comment: @juliomalves I set the main meta tags at ```main.js``` and items meta tags at ```item.js```! And it works. Is this bad habit to set meta tags in ```_document.js```? thank you!

Comment: It's fine to add them there if you don't need to overwrite them. But as a general rule of thumb I'd recommend to have them in `_app` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes it does :) Both of them helped to solve my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta tags added to the custom `_document` cannot be deduped.

To solve this constraint, you should set the default meta tags in your `_app` inside `next/head` (where they can be deduped), and overwrite them when needed in your pages.